# How to fadeIn data returned from next page?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, fadein

How to fadeIn data that are returned from next page using php
I have used following code:

```
$('#myHref').change(function(){
   var value = $('#myHref').val();
   $.get('get_projectName.php',{id:value},function(data)
   {  
      $('#projectDetail').html(data);
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `fadeIn()` works on hidden elements so you could hide your `projectDetail` using `hide()` then fadein will works :

```
$('#projectDetail').hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow');
```

Hope this helps.